# rxjs/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.js 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, systemjs, rxjs6

I've upgraded my app from Angular 5 to 6 following https://update.angular.io tutorial. The app doesn't load producing errors:

```
zone.js:1050 GET http://localhost:9000/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1050 GET http://localhost:9000/node_modules/rxjs/testing/TestScheduler.js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1050 GET http://localhost:9000/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1050 GET http://localhost:9000/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/AsyncAction.js 404 (Not Found)
```

package.json: https://pastebin.com/Qwhi63VR

systemjs.config.js: https://pastebin.com/3U7Qih1g

Any ideas what could be wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In RxJS 6 you need to import `VirtualTimeScheduler` directly from `'rxjs'`:

```
import { VirtualTimeScheduler } from 'rxjs';
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using `VirtualTimeScheduler` anywhere in my code, where would I be importing it to?

Comment: If you're not using it then what's throwing the error while requesting it?

Comment: Well, I assume it's one of the dependencies that are imported that's using it, but is there a way to find out which one? EDIT: just ran a code search on all of them, but nothing outside of `rxjs` itself uses `VirtualTimeScheduler`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a library that is not compatible with the rxjs 6 yet, you should import [rxjs-compat](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/compat) to your project.

> This package is required to get backwards compatibility with RxJS previous to version 6. It contains the imports to add operators to Observable.prototype and creation methods to Observable.

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

Comment: Thanks, installed `rxjs-compat`, but nothing changed. If it is one of the libraries that is not compatible, even though I've installed `rxjs-compat` it wouldn't start automatically using it, would it?

Comment: You probably need to use ngx-moment instead of angular2-moment, according to the github page, angular2-moment is for older angular versions : https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment

Comment: I've switched to `ngx-moment` and removed `angular2-moment`, unfortunatelly no change at all.